# Why is $f(x)=1/x$ on $[0,1]$ bounded but not on $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I'm reading Jay Cummings Real Analysis and in it he says that the continuous function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ is not bounded. This seems intuitive to me since the we can get to values $(1,\infty)$ but then he says that if we make $f(x)$ continuous on $[0,1]$ then we guarantee that $f$ is bounded. Why is this so? Can't we also get as close to zero as we want thus giving us bigger and bigger values? Isn't the range of this function now just $[1,\infty]$? How does just the fact of making the domain closed and bounded give us that the function is also bounded? Thank you for any help!

Edit: This is what the claim is verbatim: "$f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) =\frac{1}{x}$ is a continuous function on the bounded set $(0,1)$, but yet $f$ is unbounded. However, if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ then we can guarantee that $f$ is bounded; meaning that the range of $f$ is a
bounded set."

Edit 2: It seems that when he says "if $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$" he is not necessarily saying that $f(x)$ is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. That is probably where I went wrong.

Final Edit: Seems like he is just getting towards the Heine-Borel Theorem by saying that a continuous function from a compact set $A$ implies $f(A)$ is also compact and thus bounded.

Comment: Can you extend $f(x)=1/x$ continuously to $[0,1]$?

Comment: Do you have the exact wording of the claim at hand? If so, could you edit your post to include it?

Comment: It sounds to me like an extremely poor way of just saying that for some continuous functions (those that can be extended continuously), they must be bounded. It certainly is not true for the function at hand.

Comment: As suggested by the previous comments, if you leave $f(x)$ **as is**, without any alteration, then $f(x)$ is not defined at $x = 0$.  Therefore, as is, the domain of $f(x)$ can not be represented by the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, let me write the whole claim verbatim.

Comment: In general a continuous function from a closed bounded interval of reals to the reals is bounded. Of course $\frac{1}{x}$ is not such a function on $[0,1]$ (it's not defined on the entire interval; and there is no way to define it at $0$ so as to make it continuous).

Comment: My reaction to a posting like this is (in general) that there are two possibilities: Either [1] the OP (i.e. original poster) has critically misrepresented the underlying text or [2] the author has poorly worded a concept.  Unfortunately, possibility [2] is not that unusual.

Comment: I think I found my mistake. Sorry everybody

Comment: It seems to me that the author might not be referring to that same $f$. The statement is true of any continuous function on a closed, bounded interval. I.e. that second sentence could be "However, if $g(x)$ is any continuous function on $[0,1]$, then we can guarantee that $g$ is bounded."

Comment: In such a situation, reading ahead could usually solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording in the text isn't that great, creating some ambiguity.

$g(x) = \frac1x$ cannot be extended continuously to $[0,1]$ from $(0,1)$. Let us prove this by contradiction. Suppose $g$ has a continuous extension $\tilde g: [0,1]\to \Bbb R$. Then, $\tilde g(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in (0,1)$. As $\tilde g$ is continuous, we must have $$\tilde g(0) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \tilde g(h) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} g(h) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac1h = \infty \notin \mathbb R $$
which is a contradiction since $\tilde g(0)\in \mathbb R$.

Instead, consider *some function* $f$, which is continuous on $[0,1]$. Certainly, $f\ne g$. It is known (from topology) that continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets, and that compact sets in $\mathbb R$ are necessarily closed and bounded (Heine-Borel theorem). $[0,1]$ is compact, so its image under (continuous) $f$ is also compact. The image, being compact, is bounded (by the Heine-Borel theorem).